# Issue in configuring email in jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I have tried to go through all the solutions provided on stack overflow like adding a skip plugin or adding a certificate in keystore, still test email is failing with the below error, can someone help me with same. I am using a windows machine

```
Error in jenkins:sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
Caused: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(Unknown Source)
    <snip>
Caused: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)
    <snip>
Caused: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 465;
  nested exception is:
    javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1934)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:638)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:317)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:125)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:194)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
    at hudson.tasks.Mailer$DescriptorImpl.doSendTestMail(Mailer.java:585)
    <snip>
```

cmd prompt says Certificate already exists in keystore under alias .

Comment: It looks like you're trying to send e-mail via Gmail's SMTP server. Recent versions of Java should already trust Google's servers. Do you have an SSL unwrapping firewall/proxy in place or SSL unwrapping anti-virus installed on the machine running Jenkins? What version of Java are you running?

Comment: java version "1.8.0_181"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_181-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.181-b13, mixed mode)

Comment: I am really new to jenkin, can you explain on how do I perform this: "SSL unwrapping firewall/proxy in place or SSL unwrapping anti-virus installed on the machine running Jenkins"

Comment: SSL unwrapping is something some security applications and malware do in order to inspect your encrypted traffic. Basically it connects to the real server on your behalf and then has you connect to it as if you were connecting to the real server. You can usually tell based on the certificate the server replies with. Can you update your question with the output of this command: `openssl s_client -showcerts -connect smtp.gmail.com:465`? You can get openssl for Windows [here](https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html).

Answer (score 1):

Go to `https://<jenkins-url>/systemInfo` and look for `javax.net.ssl.trustStore`.
This should be the truststore where the certificate should be added.

You can open the keystore with keytool or if you prefer a GUI take a look at [Keystore Explorer](https://keystore-explorer.org/)

The default password of the truststore is `changeit`.

Comment: For a self signed certificate for a privately hosted SMTP server this is absolutely the right answer. The OP is connecting to Gmail though, and Gmail should already have a trusted certificate. This answer will work, but may obscure a security issue.

Comment: If the user has a proxy with SSL interception this might also be the right answer. The corporate IT typically just installs additional certificates only in the provided java and not at installed software.

Comment: Agreed, if the issue is SSL interception, as long as the SSL interception is expected this is the correct answer.